# Change ",00 text" to ",00 | text" in excel

Tags: excel, replace

I'd like to replace some text in a string in excel into a different string.

The data looks like: "text some more text 0,00 text some more text 0,00 text"

The text could be anything, but does not contain decimals. The 0,00 is an example for a number that could be anything ranging from 0,00 to 9999,99. With a formula, i'd like to change the example above into:

The data looks like: "text some more text 0,00 | text some more text 0,00 | text"

How can I arrange this in excel?

Looking for something like an regex replace or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily with a User Defined Function written in VBA:

```
Option Explicit
Function addPipes(S As String) As String
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim I As Long

V = Split(S)
For I = 0 To UBound(V)
    If V(I) Like "*#,#*" Then V(I) = V(I) & " |"
Next I

addPipes = Join(V)

End Function
```

Although, if your ultimate goal is to split the string on the pipes, and if you are working in VBA anyway, you can just do the split with a simple macro.

Also, if you have some words that contain the pattern of `d,d` (where `d` is a digit, we'd have to modify the `Like` comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression (UDF, user-defined function):

```
Function ReplaceText(cell)
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "(\d\s)": .Global = True
        ReplaceText = .Replace(cell, "$1| ")
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Might be a bit more robust to use `\b(\d{1,4},\d{2}\s+)` given his specifications: *ranging from 0,00 to 9999,99*

Answer (score 0):

With the original text string in A2 try,

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(A2, FIND(",", A2, FIND(",", A2)+1)+3, 1, " | "), FIND(",", A2)+3, 1, " | ")
```

There is no native worksheet regular expression but it can easily be accomplished in a VBA user defined function.

Comment: Does this also work for a string that has about 15 or 20 values of "0,00" ? Or does this work for just my initial example "text some more text 0,00 | text some more text 0,00 | text"?

Comment: No, you will need to create a user defined function with VBA and a RegEx.Replace for that.